# Selecting with linq from 2 different objects

Tags: c#, linq, select

i want to select from 2 different objects in Linq in order to compare them. This is what i tried,

```
var myItem = (from abc in firstList.Value
              from cds in secondList
              where (abc.Key.theKey == cds.secondList.theSecondKey
              select cds).SingleOrDefault();
```

although i get an error:

Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'

Comment: You need to show the structure of the objects you are selecting from.

Comment: the first list is Dictionary<ClassA, Dictionary<ClassB, ClassC>> the second is a list of ClassD.. is it good enough?

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve with your collections. I cant understand a thing from your query, because it is far from working query. Are your trying to select an item for second list based on item in first list?

Comment: That code is short a closing bracket...

Answer (score 0):

If that's your *exact* query, it may just be because you've got unmatched brackets. Try this:

```
var myItem = (from abc in firstList.Value
              from cds in secondList
              where abc.Key.theKey == cds.secondList.theSecondKey
              select cds).SingleOrDefault();
```

Admittedly I would probably rewrite that using a join - in most cases the join will be more efficient.

However, if that's *not* your exact query, please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. It's not clear why `cds` would have a `secondList` property for example. A complete example demonstrating the problem would make this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have an opening paranthesis in more:

```
var myItem = (from abc in firstList.Value
              from cds in secondList
              where abc.Key.theKey == cds.secondList.theSecondKey
              select cds
             ).SingleOrDefault();
```